# Why my view show Error: Array to string conversion

Tags: codeigniter

I make table form in controller function and call table to show in view page.

This my code in view page

```
<?php 
    foreach($tables as $table){
        echo $tables;
    }
?>
```

and this is my controller

```
$table ='';
    $tables[]= array();
    $result = array();
    $param = new stdClass();

    if(sizeof($_GET) > 0){
        $param->date_from = $this->input->get('date_from');
        $param->date_to = $this->input->get('date_to');
        $param->sales_name = $this->input->get('sales_name');
        $data['result'] = $this->m_commission->check_invoice_user ($param);
        foreach ($result as $result){
        $table = '<div>'.$result->INVOICEDATE.'</div>';
        }
        $tables[] = $table;
    }
    $data['tables'] = $tables;
    $data['team'] = $this->m_user->get_team();
    $this->load->view('v_header');
    $this->load->view('v_test', $data);
    $this->load->view('v_footer');
```

my model i'm checked query already it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first glance (echo `$table` not `$tables`):

```
<?php 
    foreach($tables as $table){
        echo $table;
    }
?>
```

**(EDIT:)** In your controller:

```
    $tables[]= array();
    $param = new stdClass();

    if(sizeof($_GET) > 0){
        $param->date_from = $this->input->get('date_from');
        $param->date_to = $this->input->get('date_to');
        $param->sales_name = $this->input->get('sales_name');
        $results = $this->m_commission->check_invoice_user ($param);
        foreach ($results as $result){
           $tables[]= '<div>'.$result->INVOICEDATE.'</div>';
        }
    }
    $data['tables'] = $tables;
    $data['team'] = $this->m_user->get_team();
    $this->load->view('v_header');
    $this->load->view('v_test', $data);
    $this->load->view('v_footer');
```

In your model, change line:

```
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            $result = $query->num_rows();
        }
        return $result;
```

to

```
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
     return $query->result();
}else return false;
```

Comment: What is the exact error, and on what line. Pinpoint that line.

Comment: please see at my answer.

Comment: You're welcome. Please take a minute to accept answer or/and up vote. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's still show error "Array to string conversion" and show " Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

This my model

```
function check_invoice_user($param){
    $result = array();
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from("bsm_salesinvoiceheader bh");
    $this->db->join("bsm_customerpayment bsmc", "bsmc.INVOICENUMBER = bh.INVOICENUMBER", 'LEFT');
    $this->db->join("bsm_salesinvoicelines bsms", "bsms.INVOICENUMBER = bh.INVOICENUMBER", 'LEFT');
    $this->db->like("bh.ADDITIONALFIELD_2", $param->sales_name, 'BOTH');
    $this->db->or_like("bh.ADDITIONALFIELD_5", $param->sales_name, 'BOTH');
    $this->db->or_like("bh.ADDITIONALFIELD_8", $param->sales_name, 'BOTH');
    $this->db->where("bh.INVOICEDATE >= ",$param->date_from);
    $this->db->where("bh.INVOICEDATE <= ",$param->date_to);
    $this->db->where("bsmc.APPLIEDDATE >= ",$param->date_from);
    $this->db->where("bsmc.APPLIEDDATE <= ",$param->date_to);
    $this->db->order_by("bh.INVOICEDATE", 'ASC');

    $query = $this->db->get();
    echo $this->db->last_query();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $result = $query->num_rows();
    }
    return $result;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

View:

```
<?php 
    foreach($tables as $table){
        echo $table;
    }
?>
```

Actually its still an Array.
just try this:

```
<?php 
print_r($tables);
    foreach($tables as $table){
        echo $table['your_column_name'];
        //print_r($table);
    }
?>
```

Comment: which one?
print_r($tables); --> if its you have to check your Database query.

Answer (score 0):

1.

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
>
> Filename: controllers/commission.php
>
> Line Number: 334
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\sales_commission\application\controllers\commission.php
>   Line: 334 Function: _error_handler
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\sales_commission\index.php Line: 292 Function:
>   require_once

2.

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Array to string conversion
>
> Filename: views/v_test.php
>
> Line Number: 21
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\sales_commission\application\views\v_test.php
>   Line: 21 Function: _error_handler
>
> File:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\sales_commission\application\controllers\commission.php
>   Line: 349 Function: view
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\sales_commission\index.php Line: 292 Function:
>   require_once

Comment: What code do we find on line 334 in your controller, and on 21 in your view?

Comment: line 334 is foreach ($results as $result){...
line 21 is echo $table